# Use Asp.Net Web API to download file from sharing folders

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a FileManagement(FM) site and multiple IIS. On each IIS, I store some files, all those files is under sharing folder. I need create a API to client, when client pass server address, physical path, FM will download file from specified IIS and return to client.

This is a path file Menu.txt put on IIS A:

App_Data\Store\Menu.txt. App_Data is sharing folder with name: \SERVER-AppData.

When I pass paramter to API, it will be like this:

Server Address: Ip address of IISA

Path: \SERVER-AppData\Store\Menu.txt

I use WebClient to download in Test API project.

```
// Create a new WebClient instance
WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
myWebClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");

// Concatenate the domain with the Web resource filename.
string myStringWebResource = Path.Combine(serverAddress, path);
string store = @"E:\file.txt";

// Download the Web resource and save it into the current filesystem folder.
byte[] bytes = myWebClient.DownloadData(myStringWebResource);
```

When I run it, it said: username or password is wrong. But in Network in Window Explorer. I connect to that server with username and password is correct.

Answer (score -2):

Store the files in  a database rather than a physical file.

You can then download from any of the attached IIS machines.

Comment: I cannot store the file in DB, files in store on each IIS